# What are the database options for android web apps?

Tags: android, database, web-applications

Im creating an app because I need it personally. Im using HTML, CSS3 and AngularJs. So I thought I could actually sell in on Google Play. Simply by implementing the website in a webView. User can add/edit/remove data within the app.

I dont want to store them on an online server because that would require internet connection and user registration. The app should work without any internet connection.

What options do I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest adding a custom javascript interface with the webview to add and remove items from a [SQLite Database](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

How about making it pure HTML5, and using the built in database?

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webdatabase/todo/

webdatabase apparently deprecated, but is supported in my Droid 2, and you could easily write your code to work with either a webdatabase or an IndexedDB